# How to make text of an alert box selected?

Tags: javascript, alert, selection

Is there a way to make the text `Hello` automatically selected inside popup box when using `alert` method?

```js
alert("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `prompt` instead of `alert`:

```js
prompt("This is a prompt with preselected text", "some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are not part of DOM, they are a part of browser. And for many reasons including security, your script does not have access to the browser's API directly.

So you can't select alert's text automatically.